# How can I subselect a value in django querySelector?

Tags: python, django, filter

I will exlplain my question with an example:

lets say I am able to extract an object with this form with my filter:

`{ a, b, c : {x, y, z} }`

But what I am trying to do, is to get the object as following:

`{ a, b, c : {x} }`

`{ a, b, c : {y} }`

`{ a, b, c : {z} }`

*if my  question isn't clear enough don't hesitate to ask for more details in the comments*

Code

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    number_of_comments = models.IntegerField()
    number_of_pingbacks = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
```

Filter:

```py
Entry.objects.all().filter(pub_date__year=2006)
```

It is possible that I have multiple Author for the same Entry.

I would like to edit my filter querySet in order to be able to get multiple row for an entry based on each autor, for example if I have two author for an entry I would like to have in the result two entry with each one having an author name.

Comment: Post example of code with result and wanted result please. it could be more clear for helping you

Comment: Can we use the prefetch_related in this case?

Comment: Please provide some code of your attempt to solve your issue. So we can understand and reproduce the problem you're facing.

Comment: @CristianoSchiaffella I have updated y question

Comment: I have updated my question, I hope it's clear now @LucasGrugru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a queryset from author for getting what you want to:

```
queryset = Author.objects.filter(entry_set__pub_date__year=2006)
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related("entry_set")
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related("entry_set__author_set")
queryset = queryset.prefetch_related("entry_set__blog")
```

With this queryset you can loop into author and for each one, you can loop into entries, is it what you want ?

```
{% for author in queryset %}
    {{author.name}}
    {% for entry in author.entry_set.all %}
        {{entry.blog.name}}
        {{entry.headline}}
        {% for author in entry.author_set.all %}
            {{author.name %}
        {% enffor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```